# How to handle this exception by try catch ? AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_text'

Tags: exception, beautifulsoup, try-catch, tweets

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hf8LD.png)
I want to fetch the trends as shown in the images but i am not able to fetch the tweets which has no tweet counts.(refer the image) below is the error i am getting for those tweets which has no tweet counts. Please let me know how to handle the this exception and print all the tweets.

```
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    import requests
    URL = "https://trends24.in/india/"
    html_text=requests.get(URL)
    soup= BeautifulSoup(html_text.content,'html.parser')
    results = soup.find(id='trend-list')
    job_elems = results.find_all('li')
    for job_elem in job_elems:
            print(job_elem.find('a').get_text(), job_elem.find('span').get_text())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could select for a shared parent then wrap the attempt to grab with tweet-count inside the try except

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
URL = "https://trends24.in/india/"
html_text=requests.get(URL)
soup= BeautifulSoup(html_text.content,'lxml')

for i in soup.select('#trend-list li'):
    print(i.a.text)
    try:
        print(i.select_one('.tweet-count').text)
    except:
        print("no tweets")
```

---

List of dicts:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
URL = "https://trends24.in/india/"
html_text=requests.get(URL)
soup= BeautifulSoup(html_text.content,'lxml')

results = []

for i in soup.select('#trend-list li'):
    d = dict()
    d[i.a.text] = '' 
    try:
        val = i.select_one('.tweet-count').text
    except:
        val = "no tweets"
    finally:
        d[i.a.text] = val
        results.append(d)
```

Comment: required output should be in key value pairs ! by this method its getting little complicated. advise if you know how to convert output to dict/key value example = {'Happy easter':'123K'},{'Good friday','No tweets'} like that

Comment: @PrashantPatil you've received an answer according to what you asked for. but going from an answer to a new question isn't how the community built on! Please check [ask] and be informed that we are limited to provide an answer according to the initial question asked

Comment: That worked . thank you.  Aplology ! this is my first question on this community. I will keep in mind from next time.